# Adding div to jquery filter

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery & I'm over the moon that I have been able to create the following filter for my website, what I want to do next is when someone clicks an option e.g photoshop, how can I then apply the following div -

```
<span id="all" class="label label-primary">photoshop</span>
```

Then if they click another option such as all I need to remove that div from photoshop and put it on all.

```
$("#all").click(function(){
    $(".webdesign").show();
    $(".photoshop").show();
    $(".games").show();
})
$("#webdesign").click(function(){
    $(".webd").show();
    $(".photoshop").hide();
    $(".games").hide();
})
$("#photoshop").click(function(){
    $(".webd").hide();
    $(".photoshop").show();
    $(".games").hide();
})
$("#games").click(function(){
    $(".webd").hide();
    $(".photoshop").hide();
    $(".games").show();
})
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the relevant html? Selectors like `.webdesign` etc. wouldn't match anything as it is now...

Comment: can you provide more context to the question of adding your markup

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the div"?

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle but it didn't even work, I'm sorry if this isn't allowed im sure someone will remove the link but the markup can be found here - http://xronn.co.uk/portfolio.php

I want to add that bootstrap background pill effect to the filter that is active see top of page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/38sYd/3/)

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="labels">
  <span id="all" class="label active">All</span>
  <span id="photoshop" class="label">Photoshop</span>
  <span id="games" class="label">Games</span>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="photoshop"></div>
  <div class="games"></div>
  <div class="photoshop"></div>
  <div class="games"></div>
  <div class="photoshop"></div>
  <div class="games"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.label.active {
  background-color: #4EB478;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em .6em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #4EB478;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
}

.photoshop {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #321;
}

.games {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #789;
}
```

And the JavaScript

```
$("#all").click(function(){
  $("#container div").show();
})
$("#webdesign").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("#container div").hide();
  $('.webd').show();
})
$("#photoshop").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("#container div").hide();
  $('.photoshop').show();
})
$("#games").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("#container div").hide();
  $('.games').show();
})
```

Comment: I believe he has this working already, just missing the highlight of the currently active button, if i understand correctly

Comment: Yeah, I want the filter text that you click to have the "pill" background effect used in the span tag to represent that it has been successfully clicked and is actively showing that option

Comment: Yeah, but so the green background is removed if you aren't on that selection at the moment they all have green backgrounds, I only want the one that is clicked to have the background

Comment: Nailed it thanks! Didn't expect all that thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

If all you're missing is the highlight, you can try something like this (merged into what you got)

```
$(".filter > li").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Adding to @Graham's demo, it would be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/38sYd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how do you want to place you `span`. You can do either way:

```
var html = "<span id="all" class="label label-primary">photoshop</span>";
$("#someid").on('click', function(){
 //stuff
 $(this).append(html);
 //or
 //$(html).insertAfter($(this));
});
```

if you want to remove use

```
$("#someid").on('click',function(){
 if($("#all").length > 1){ //lets check if the span exist 
   $("#all").remove();
 }
//then append or insertafter
});
```